# K-Nearest-Neighbour

Tags: r, dataset

I'm trying to use the `knn` function that comes in the `class` library of R. It's giving me an error that "train" is not the same length as "class".

Upon printing the lengths of train and class respectively, I found that train has a length of 100 (as needed) and class has a length of 2 (as expected). If I understand correctly, `cl`, or class, is meant to be a factored vector of labels. My labels are just "orange" and "blue". I followed the example in the documentation yet the error persists. Is there something glaringly wrong with my code? Any help is appreciated.

```
library(class)

x <- runif(100, 1, 100)
y <- runif(100, 1, 100)
train.df <- data.frame(x, y)

x.test <- runif(100, 1, 100)
y.test <- runif(100, 1, 100)
test.df <- data.frame(x.test, y.test)

cl <- factor(c(rep("orange", 100), rep("blue", 100)))

knn(train.df, test.df, cl, k=3, prob=TRUE)
```

Comment: `cl` is 200 elements long. Try calling `rep` 50 times for each class instead.

Comment: That did the trick. If you'd like to post your comment as an answer I can check it off. Thanks!

Comment: Questions about how to use R / error messages are off topic here. This will be on topic on [SO]. If you can wait, we will migrate it there for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cl` is 200 elements long. Try calling `rep` 50 times for each class instead.

```
library(class)

x <- runif(100, 1, 100)
y <- runif(100, 1, 100)
train.df <- data.frame(x, y)

x.test <- runif(100, 1, 100)
y.test <- runif(100, 1, 100)
test.df <- data.frame(x.test, y.test)

cl <- factor(c(rep("orange", 50), rep("blue", 50)))

knn(train.df, test.df, cl, k=3, prob=TRUE)
```